# Get current CPU usage using PowerCLI

Tags: powershell, vsphere, powercli, vcenter

On the vSphere client host summary page, current CPU usage stats are displayed:

```
CPU                 Free: 76.38 GHz
Used: 4.02 GHz      Capacity: 80.4 GHz
```

I am trying to retrieve this information using `PowerCLI`, so far I have discovered this property:

```
$vmhost = Get-VMHost
$vmhost.ExtensionData.Summary.Hardware
```

This property displays CPU information including model, cores, threads etc. but not current usage as a percentage.

Is this possible using `PowerCLI`?

PowerCLI version: 6.5
PowerShell version: 5.1

Comment: `Get-VMHost | Get-VM | Get-Stat -CPU -Memory -Realtime` maybe? (from the [vSphere PowerCLI Reference](https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-51/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.powercli.cmdletref.doc%2FGet-Stat.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, you'll want to get comfortable with `Get-Stat`

There are 3 stat types that you can reference for CPU stats:

- cpu.usage.average
- cpu.usagemhz.average
- cpu.ready.summation

(Other stat types can be found using `Get-StatType`)

You can pull the stats with the following:

```
$vmhost | Get-Stat -Stat cpu.usagemhz.average
```

However, if you just want the most current value:

```
$vmhost | Get-Stat -Stat cpu.usagemhz.average -Realtime -MaxSamples 1
```